# SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM with linqtosql

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

i have some problem with entering current date to sql with using linqtosql model.

here is my code :

```
using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
{
    List<string> file_names = null;
    if (Session["new_flag"].ToString() == "True")
    {
        Email myEmail = new Email();
        myEmail.Title = txt_ComName.Text.Trim();
        myEmail.ToUser = txt_ComName1.Text.Trim();
        myEmail.Body = CKEditor1.Text.Trim();
        if (file_upload.HasFile)
        {
            myEmail.IsFileAttached = true;
        }
        else
        {
            myEmail.IsFileAttached = false;
        }
        myEmail.SentDateTime = DateTime.Parse(System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
        db.Emails.InsertOnSubmit(myEmail);
        db.SubmitChanges();
```

here i have found this error :

```
Server Error in '/NewsLetter' Application.

SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

Source Error: 


Line 442:                    myEmail.SentDateTime = DateTime.Parse(System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
Line 443:                    db.Emails.InsertOnSubmit(myEmail);
Line 444:                    db.SubmitChanges();
Line 445:                    int newId = myEmail.Id;
Line 446:                    HttpFileCollection fileCollection = Request.Files;

Source File: f:\NewsLetter\Default.aspx.cs    Line: 444 

Stack Trace: 


[SqlTypeException: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.]
   System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan value) +2131361
   System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.FromDateTime(DateTime value) +232
   System.Data.SqlClient.MetaType.FromDateTime(DateTime dateTime, Byte cb) +46
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.WriteValue(Object value, MetaType type, Byte scale, Int32 actualLength, Int32 encodingByteSize, Int32 offset, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +5002013
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteRPC(_SqlRPC[] rpcArray, Int32 timeout, Boolean inSchema, SqlNotificationRequest notificationRequest, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isCommandProc) +6248
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) +987
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) +162
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +32
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +141
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +12
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader() +12
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult) +1266
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries) +113
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query) +344
   System.Data.Linq.StandardChangeDirector.DynamicInsert(TrackedObject item) +151
   System.Data.Linq.StandardChangeDirector.Insert(TrackedObject item) +235
   System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode) +337
   System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode) +378
   System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges() +23
   _Default.submit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in f:\NewsLetter\Default.aspx.cs:444
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

i found this error every time submitting current date value to sql. how ever i resolve this with this statement :

```
DateTime.Parse(System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

please help me...

Comment: Error is self explanatory. You must be trying to insert DateTime which is outside the permissible limit of SQLDateTime. Do validation before inserting value. Simple as that.

Comment: Why would you convert it to a string and then parse it? Why not just use `DateTime.Now`? (Consider storing UTC though, rather than local time...) Are there any other `DateTime` values in your entity?

Comment: yes i have another datetime field like in same entity

Comment: i have two datetime field one is nullable and other is non-nullable datetime field.

Comment: I guess your problem is here... myEmail.SentDateTime = DateTime.Parse(System.DateTime.Now.ToString()); it is probably null and giving some default time that causes the sqldatetime overflow... detect if it's null then create your own default that doesn't break it.

Comment: How did you solve it?  Using the DateTime.Parse 'hack'?  Having same problem here.

Comment: Same issue here - how did you solve it?